# Não consigo colocar uma div ao lado da outra

Tags: html, css, div

Estou começando agora em HTML e CSS e estou montando um portifólio próprio, porém estou tendo um problema ao colocar um conteúdo ao lado do outro, ele acaba indo para baixo, vou colocar a imagem no fim da pergunta.

Eu gostaria que o conteúdo fosse para onde está apontando a flecha, alinhando com a imagem central e os links abaixo da mesma.

O que eu tenho de código até agora é o seguinte:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Currículo Liep Böeger</title>
    </head>     
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="cabecalho">
                <h1>Liep Böeger</h1>
                <h4>Estudante de Sistemas de Informação</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="conteudo-central">
                <center>
                    <img id = "imagem" src="Imagens/PerfilLinkedIn.jpg" alt="">
                </center>
                <div id="social-media">
                    <a  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/liep-boeger-065648216/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>
                    <a  href="https://github.com/LiepBoeger" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="informacoes-pessoais">
                <strong>Residência</strong>
                <p>xxxxxxxxxx</p>
                <strong>Telefone</strong>
                <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                <strong>E-mail</strong>
                <p><e-mail>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</e-mail></p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #acacac;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cabecalho {
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(66, 64, 64);
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#informacoes-pessoais {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(66, 64, 64);
    width: 180px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

#imagem {
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #acacac url(Imagens/PerfilLinkedIn.jpg) center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#social-media {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

#social-media a{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(66, 64, 64);
    background: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#conteudo-central{
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image: Imagem com o problema]

Answer (score 0):

No `#informacoes-pessoais` adiciona a propriedade `float: left;` e vê se fica do jeito que você que.